Absolute continuity of quadratic variation of continuous semimartingales
I am having trouble making sense of Remark 3.18 of Stochastic Calculus in Manifolds by Emery. The remark is about manifold-valued semimartingales but I cannot even make sense of it when the manifold is $\mathbb{R}^n$. So, for simplicity, I am going to rewrite the remark for the $\mathbb{R}^n$ case.
Let $\boldsymbol{X}=(X^1,\dots,X^n)$ be an $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued continuous semimartingale (or a local martingale). The book claims that one can attach to $\boldsymbol{X}$, a continuous increasing process $A$ and $n^2$ real-valued processes $(V^{ij})^{i,j\in\{1,\dots,n\}}$ such that $$\int_0^t b_{ij}(\boldsymbol{X}_s)d[X^i,X^j]_s=\int_0^t b_{ij}(\boldsymbol{X}_s)V^{ij}_sdA_s,$$ for any collection of (smooth) maps $b_{ij}:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$, where $[X^i,X^j]$ is the quadratic covariation. It claims this can be done by defining $A=\sum_{ij}\int|d[X^i,X^j]|$ and choosing $V^{ij}$'s such that $d[X^i,X^j]=V^{ij}dA$.
If I understand this correctly, it claims that all the quadratic variations $[X^i,X^j]$ are absolutely continuous w.r.t a single random measure $dA$ and $V^{ij}=\frac{d[X^i,X^j]}{dA}$, in the Radon–Nikodym (RN) sense. However,
1-I cannot parse what the definition of $A=\sum_{ij}\int|d[X^i,X^j]|$ even mean, especially with the sum. Is it summing the total variation measures of random measures $[X^i,X^j]$'s? How can you get a single process out of this such that all of $[X^i,X^j]$ become RN-differentiable w.r.t $A$?
2-Even if we set $n=1$, how do we know that $d[X^1,X^1]$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t $|d[X^1,X^1]|$?
P.s. Here is an screenshot of the original text:


For the $\mathbb{R}^d$ case you can also look at Jacod-Shiryaev Prop. 2.9 p. 77 and its proof
